# Vector array not showing correct ans but cout<<array[0] is right

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6PSo.png) [Leetcode 189](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT4IF.png)
Why is the answer coming wrong?
The vector array temp when returned shows wrong answer but when i cout using traversal it is completely right. where am i going wrong?
please help xx

i was doing right rotation of the array nums. created a vector array temp, and applied my own logic and wrote the code,the answer is not matching,
FYI the nums in the TC is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and k=3
PFA, the code and the output

```
using namespace std;
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> rotate(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        int n=nums.size();
        vector<int>temp(n);

        //copying last k elements in temp
        for(int i=n-k; i<n; i++){
            temp[i-(n-k)] = nums[i];
        }
        //remain
        for(int i=0; i<(n-k); i++){
            temp[i+k] = nums[i];
        }
        cout<<temp[0];
        return temp;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please post code as properly formatted text in your question.

Comment: Please see [ask].

Comment: Any stray output that is not specifically asked for by the question can invalidate the result.

Comment: This will work very badly when k > n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not wrong you changed the firm of the `rotate` method.
The original question had a `void rotate(vector<int>& nums, int k)`. So `temp` that  you are returning there, is probably just ignored by the problem.

You should modify `nums` instead.